# apache cxf wsdl2java Failed to generate types->Access is denied

Tags: java, cxf, wsdl2java

I'm struggling to fix this issue since 2013...
I'm using Windows 7.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.1.2:wsdl2java (generate-sources)
>   on project service-data-model-provider: Execution generate-sources of
>   goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.1.2:wsdl2java failed: Failed
>   to generate types.
>   a:\Misc\WsMock\service-data-model-provider\src\main\java\schema\eo\common\system\messageheader\v1\MessageContextType.java
>   (Access is denied) -> [Help 1]

Its completely random and happens for me on all cxf versions and different java versions.
At the moment I'm on jdk 1.8.45 and cxf 3.1.2

The issue can be resolved by setting always

But then the build is always successful even is some errors will happen which are shown as [Warning] in the log.. So I can't use anything like that.

Here's my cfg

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <sourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceRoot>
                <defaultOptions>
                    <extraargs>
                        <extraarg>-validate</extraarg>
                        <extraarg>-exsh</extraarg>
                        <extraarg>true</extraarg>
                    </extraargs>
                </defaultOptions>
                <wsdlRoot>..\..\..</wsdlRoot>
                <includes>
                    <include>mds/apps/services/**/*.wsdl</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Another thing that helps but its not resolving the issue completely is to disable the WriteToCache setting in the WindowsHardDrive driver.

That indicates that the system is too slow and CXF\Java is trying to use the file before its completely written to the disk.
Using an SSD the issue is happening only occasionally.

Our data model is huge (lots of XSD's) and the hard drives are encrypted so that's why everything is so slow.

Any ideas how to tune java to handle this? Or maybe its a CXF problem?

Full Stack Trace

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.1.2:wsdl2java (generate-sources)
>   on project service-data-model-provider: Execution generate-sources of
>   goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.1.2:wsdl2java failed: Fai led
>   to generate types.
>   a:\Misc\WsMock\service-data-model-provider\src\main\java\co\schema\common\fault\creati
>   onfault\v1\ObjectFactory.java (Access is denied) -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.1.2:w sdl2java
>   (generate-sources) on project service-data-model-provider: Execution
>   generate-sources of goal org.apache.cx
>   f:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.1.2:wsdl2java failed: Failed to generate types.
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:224)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.
>   java:51)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
>   Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution
>   generate-sources of goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codeg
>   en-plugin:3.1.2:wsdl2java failed: Failed to generate types.
>           at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
>           ... 20 more Caused by: org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolException: Failed to generate types.
>           at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.databinding.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.generate(JAXBDataBinding.java:839)
>           at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.generateTypes(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:730)
>           at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.processWsdl(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:270)
>           at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:164)
>           at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJavaContainer.execute(WSDLToJavaContainer.java:415)
>           at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:103)
>           at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:113)
>           at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:86)
>           at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.wsdl2java.WSDL2JavaMojo.generate(WSDL2JavaMojo.java:415)
>           at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.AbstractCodegenMoho.execute(AbstractCodegenMoho.java:260)
>           at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.wsdl2java.WSDL2JavaMojo.execute(WSDL2JavaMojo.java:512)
>           at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
>           ... 21 more Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: a:\Misc\WsMock\service-data-model-provider\src\main\java\uk\co\schema\
>   common\fault\creationfault\v1\ObjectFactory.java (Access is denied)
>           at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
>           at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
>           at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:213)
>           at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:162)
>           at org.sonatype.plexus.build.incremental.DefaultBuildContext.newFileOutputStream(DefaultBuildContext.java:54)
>           at org.apache.cxf.maven_plugin.wsdl2java.WSDL2JavaMojo$1.createOutputStream(WSDL2JavaMojo.java:411)
>           at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.databinding.jaxb.TypesCodeWriter.openBinary(TypesCodeWriter.java:72)
>           at com.sun.codemodel.CodeWriter.openSource(CodeWriter.java:100)
>           at com.sun.codemodel.JPackage.createJavaSourceFileWriter(JPackage.java:490)
>           at com.sun.codemodel.JPackage.build(JPackage.java:441)
>           at com.sun.codemodel.JCodeModel.build(JCodeModel.java:311)
>           at com.sun.codemodel.JCodeModel.build(JCodeModel.java:301)
>           at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.databinding.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.generate(JAXBDataBinding.java:827)
>           ... 32 more [ERROR] [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. [ERROR] [ERROR] For more information
>   about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following
>   articles: [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException

Cheers
Prem

Comment: The disable write to cache is a very good tip. Thx!

Answer (score 4):

(Moving @Prem's comment to this answer and adding more details)

Adding `<fork>always</fork>` fixes the issue.

Sample configurations:

```xml
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>generate-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
              <fork>always</fork>
            </configuration>
...
<!-- Rest of the configuration -->
```

Docs - [maven-cxf-codegen - other config](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html#Mavencxf-codegen-plugin(WSDLtoJava)-Otherconfigurationoptions)

Answer (score 0):

The same had happened with me..
I too had jdk 1.8 and cxf 3.1.x
I tried the same task on a old PC with jdk 1.7 and cxf 2.7.0 and it worked like charm..

Adding the < plugin > will generate schema and service from wsdl everytime you create a build.. I don't know whether it is a efficient way or not, but I extracted the schema and service once and added them to the root. 
Thanks

Comment: We'll its not an option for me as I have to regenerate the schemas every time I build the project.

Comment: @Prem You should try on a Java 7 PC... Read the first FAQ from this official CXF website.. 
http://cxf.apache.org/faq.html#FAQ-CanCXFrunwithJDK1.8/Java8?

Comment: I've tried and I'm getting the same. 
Using fast ssd or using cxf with enabled fork=always everything works fine. But that's not an option for me and I'm still looking for the real issue behind this.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar kind of problem when I had problem in my wsdl file. Please check the wsdl file and any missing file path.